# Unintentionally deleting a character in Console when changing the position of another character

Tags: vb.net, console-application, keypress

I'm trying to make the start of a game on Console, containing a 20 by 40 array of characters. All of the characters are "-", representing the default background for the game board, except for the "@" character, which represents the player of the game. The player position is held in an integer array.

The user can press the arrow keys to move the @ character. I've set up a loop to read the keypress, and after checking that the player character would not move out of the bounds of the array if it were to move in that direction, it firstly sets the cursor position to where the player is and replaces the "@" with a "-", updates the player position, then sets the cursor position to the new position and writes in the "@".

For some reason, when I move the character down, left or up (but not right), it deletes the "-" character that was to the right of the player's previous position, like so:

[image]

[image]

After debugging, the error happens immediately after cki = Console.ReadKey, so something about the keypress action is deleting the character, but I can't work out why it's doing that or how to stop it from doing so. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Here's the code for the loop:

```
 Dim cki As ConsoleKeyInfo
 Console.CursorVisible = False

    While True
        'Reads keypress - **deleted character occurs after this line**
        cki = Console.ReadKey
        Select Case cki.Key
            Case ConsoleKey.UpArrow
                If playerPos(0) - 1 >= 0 Then
                    'Deletes playerChar, replaces it with boardChar
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(playerPos(1), playerPos(0))
                    Console.Write(boardChar)
                    board(playerPos(0), playerPos(1)) = boardChar

                    'Changes player position along the vertical axis (-1)
                    playerPos(0) -= 1

                    'Rewrites the playerChar in the new position
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(playerPos(1), playerPos(0))
                    Console.Write(playerChar)
                    board(playerPos(0), playerPos(1)) = playerChar
                End If

            Case ConsoleKey.DownArrow
                If playerPos(0) + 1 < board.GetLength(0) Then
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(playerPos(1), playerPos(0))
                    Console.Write(boardChar)
                    board(playerPos(0), playerPos(1)) = boardChar

                    'Changes player position along the vertical axis (+1)
                    playerPos(0) += 1

                    Console.SetCursorPosition(playerPos(1), playerPos(0))
                    Console.Write(playerChar)
                    board(playerPos(0), playerPos(1)) = playerChar
                End If

            Case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow
                If playerPos(1) - 1 >= 0 Then
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(playerPos(1), playerPos(0))
                    Console.Write(boardChar)
                    board(playerPos(0), playerPos(1)) = boardChar

                    'Changes player position along the horizontal axis (-1)
                    playerPos(1) -= 1

                    Console.SetCursorPosition(playerPos(1), playerPos(0))
                    Console.Write(playerChar)
                    board(playerPos(0), playerPos(1)) = playerChar
                End If

            Case ConsoleKey.RightArrow
                If playerPos(1) + 1 < board.GetLength(1) Then
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(playerPos(1), playerPos(0))
                    Console.Write(boardChar)
                    board(playerPos(0), playerPos(1)) = boardChar

                    'Changes player position along the vertical axis (+1)
                    playerPos(1) += 1

                    Console.SetCursorPosition(playerPos(1), playerPos(0))
                    Console.Write(playerChar)
                    board(playerPos(0), playerPos(1)) = playerChar
                End If
        End Select
    End While
```

Comment: Basically pressing the arrow keys (the real ones, not on the numpad) causes a blank character to be typed, which I don't want. I can't work out how to suppress the blank character being typed.

Comment: Ah, I've figured out the solution. It's Console.ReadKey(True) which I forgot to add.